# SQL EncryptByKey not working on insert, works on update

Tags: sql-server, encryption, insert

I'm implementing encryption into an insert query , however on decryption the code is unreadable. however - when i encrypt the same record by using update, the record is decrypted correctly

to test , I used the following code to determine what's going on

```
SELECT
 EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Data_Enc_Key'), 'abc123') as Encrypted,
 CONVERT(nvarchar(50),DecryptByKey(
    CONVERT(varbinary(128),EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Data_Enc_Key'), 'abc123'))
 )) as Decrypted
```

in theory, it should encrypt and 
the same value 'abc123' but it doesn't

on the actual table I'm getting a similar set of characters on decrypt as the above query for the records that are inserted using encrypted insert

Anyone has any idea what's going on ?

```
--OPEN CERTIFICATE
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Enc_Key DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ENC_CERT

----WORKS
Update tblMembers
SET password_enc = EncryptByKey(
        Key_GUID('Enc_Key'),
        password
        )
WHERE
id = XXX
AND email = XXX

----DOES NOT WORK - ON DECRYPTION INCORRECT RESULT
INSERT INTO tblMembers (email,password,password_enc) VALUES ('abc@mail.com','abc123', EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Enc_Key'),'abc123'))


-- DECRYPT FOR BOTH INSERT AND UPDATE
select 
TOP 5 *
,
        CONVERT(nvarchar,
            DecryptByKey(
                password_enc                
                )
            )

from tblMembers
WHERE id = XXX
AND email = XXX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use `nvarchar` for `'abc123'` so the first SELECT statement should be

```
SELECT
 EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Data_Enc_Key'), N'abc123') as Encrypted,
 CONVERT(nvarchar(50),DecryptByKey(
    CONVERT(varbinary(128),EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Data_Enc_Key'), N'abc123'))
 )) as Decrypted
```

Comment: Awesome!, works - I've been trying to get it to work since this afternoon

Answer (score 0):

The following INSERT code is working:

```
INSERT INTO tblMembers (email,password,password_enc)
VALUES (
   'abc@mail.com',
   'abc123', 
   EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Enc_Key'), N'abc123')
)
```

The last line **EncryptByKey** requires the string **abc123** has **N** before the string.